# cannot load such file -- ruby-wmi (LoadError) & cannot load such file -- win32/service (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, chef-infra

I did install below mentioned ruby stuff

[image]

when i try executing chef-client, i receive below mentioned error

```
c:\RubyDevKit>chef-client
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- ruby-wmi (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.4/lib/chef/provider/env/windows.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.4/lib/chef/providers.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.4/lib/chef.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-10.14.4/bin/chef-client:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
```

Ruby193 folder Structure ( Missing )

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message `cannot load such file -- ruby-wmi (LoadError)` is coming up because `chef-client` cannot find the required gems.

This issue is addressed on the [Opscode/Chef wiki page on Common Errors](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Common+Errors#CommonErrors-Nosuchfiletoloadrubywmi).

As mentioned there, install the required gems with the following commands:

```
C:\> gem install win32-open3 ruby-wmi windows-api windows-pr --no-rdoc --no-ri --verbose
C:\> gem install rdp-ruby-wmi
```

Comment: Isn't gem supposed to detect and install dependencies like these?

Comment: needed gem install win32-service as well

Answer (score 7):

As **Prakash Murthy** said, It was missing ruby-wmi files. Thought it will help if anyone get stuck again

I did run these commands

```
C:\> gem install win32-open3 ruby-wmi windows-api windows-pr --no-rdoc --no-ri --verbose
C:\> gem install rdp-ruby-wmi
```

Got one more error

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in require': cannot load such file -- win32/service (LoadError)
```

So i would recommend

(i) check gem installed ( in CMD )

```
gem list
```

this will pointout missing gems, in my case win32/service was misisng

(ii) `gem install win32-service`

check gem list again to make sure & should fix the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Chef do not use ruby-wmi, so you should not need the gem. I got this error while trying to run test kitchen, and I have tried the solutions above but they didn't work.

This worked for me:

- Uninstall and re-install Vagrant
- Delete C:\Users\USERNAME.vagrant.d\gems folder
- Delete C:\Users\USERNAME.vagrant.d\plugins.json file

After that kitchen runs fine.