# Gem net/ping in ruby

Tags: ruby, tcp, ping

I just install net/ping gem and I want to do this program:

```
require 'net/ping'



good = 'www.google.com'
bad  = 'foo.bar.baz'

p1 = Net::Ping::TCP.new(good, 'http')
p p1.ping?

p2 = Net::Ping::TCP.new(bad)
p p2.ping?
```

The problem is when I try to run it. The system show this:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- win32/security (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ping-1.7.7/lib/net/ping/icmp.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ping-1.7.7/lib/net/ping.rb:9:in `require_relative'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ping-1.7.7/lib/net/ping.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Ildefonso7/Desktop/tcp.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

What happen???

Comment: Your error message says `cannot load such file -- win32/security (LoadError)`. It is displaying because you're missing a required gem: `win32/security`. You need to do `gem install win32-security`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot load such file -- ruby-wmi (LoadError) & cannot load such file -- win32/service (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868121/cannot-load-such-file-ruby-wmi-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-win32-s)

Comment: This seems like a bug to me.  Why isn't it that `win32-security` is a transitive dependency of `net/ping` or better yet packaged by default in Ruby for Windows?  It'd be nice to have more consistency in Ruby environments across Windows, Linux, and MacOS.